# Listing permissions of Android application via adb

Tags: android, permissions, adb, android-permissions, aapt

Using adb, how can I find out the which permissions an Android application requires?

Because I want to display the permissions of multiple applications on different devices, viewing them in `Google Play` or `Settings` > `Applications manager` requires too much manual work.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

I just wanted to combine Jason's and Juuso's answers together and notice that the former lists permissions that were *granted*, while the latter lists permissions that were *requested* (including ones that were granted).

To see *only permissions that were granted* (but omitting ones that were requested but not granted) use

```
adb shell dumpsys package packagename
```

and check `grantedPermissions` section at the bottom of the output.

To list *all permissions* (requested but not granted + requested and granted):

1. Notice the APK of a package. You can run the same command

   ```
   adb shell dumpsys package packagename
   ```

   and get the APK path from `codePath` element of its output.
2. (if there is no `aapt` on your device/emulator) You'll need to pull the apk from device/emulator as Juuso Ohtonen has pointed out in his answer. So execute something like this from your desktop:

   ```
   adb pull /data/app/com.your.package.apk
   ```
3. List all permissions of the package

   If missing from device/emulator `aapt` can be found under `build-tools/<version>/`in your Android SDK.

   Then execute

   ```
   aapt d permissions /path/to/com.your.package.apk
   ```

Comment: Say, I've noticed that "adb shell dumpsys package" command shows many kinds of information about the app. Can it also show all folders that the app officially uses, such as the external storage (on "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/PACKAGE_NAME" on my device)  ?

Comment: Grep highlighting is your friend here `adb shell dumpsys package com.example | grep --color -E "granted=true|$"`

Comment: `dumpsys` won't give you all permissions. A way to get all default Android permissions is to use `dumpsys` i.c.w. `appops`. There are different kind of permissions; for example one accepting `allow`, `deny`, `ignore`, `default` and another accepting simply `false` and `true`. `aapt` is not available on all systems so I urge everyone to use `ADB` since it's cross-platform.

Answer (score 28):

The fast way:
adb shell dumpsys package packagename | grep permission

Comment: This will only list permissions that were granted, see my answer below

Comment: Doesn't it only include permissions that have the word "pemission" in them?

Comment: on a Windows machine use: `adb shell "dumpsys package packagename | grep permission"`

Answer (score 22):

1. List all applications along with their installation paths (use `-3` flag if you're only interested in 3rd party apps). As an example, let's try to find out YouTube app permissions. 
   `adb shell pm list packages -f`

   Output:

   > ...
   >   package:/data/app/com.google.android.youtube-1.apk=com.google.android.youtube
   >   
   > ...
2. Pull the selected apk from the device: 
   `adb pull /data/app/com.google.android.youtube-1.apk`
3. List the permissions with 
   `aapt d permissions com.google.android.youtube-1.apk`

Output:

```
    uses-permission: android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY
    uses-permission: android.permission.CALL_PHONE
    uses-permission: android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED
    uses-permission: android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
    uses-permission: android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
    uses-permission: android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
    uses-permission: android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG
    uses-permission: android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
    uses-permission: android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG
    uses-permission: android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
    uses-permission: android.permission.INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW
    uses-permission: android.permission.ADD_SYSTEM_SERVICE
    uses-permission: android.permission.VIBRATE
    uses-permission: android.permission.BLUETOOTH
    uses-permission: android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
    uses-permission: android.permission.REORDER_TASKS
    uses-permission: android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION
    ...
```

> ...

Comment: Nice answer but why do you need step 2? It works fine without it.

Comment: @DenisKniazhev The `aapt` tool is not provided in the adb shell

Comment: @coco_ You're right, I must have been using an emulator with `aapt` pre-installed.

Answer (score 3):

`dumpsys` won't give you all permissions. A way to get all default Android permissions is to use `dumpsys` i.c.w. `appops`. There are different kind of permissions; for example one accepting `allow`, `deny`, `ignore`, `default` and the another accepting simply `false` and `true`. `aapt` is not available on all systems (although I like it very much) so I urge everyone to use `ADB` since it's cross-platform.

A short answer without going in detail to get all permissions:

- `adb shell pm list permissions` lists permissions that comes with
  installed apps (`false` or `true`)
- `adb shell cmd appops get <package>` lists permissions on
  user level per app (`allow`, `deny`, `ignore`)
- `adb shell dumpsys <package>` lists permissions per app on system
  level (`grant` and `revoke`)