# How to solve this adb grant permission error

Tags: android, permissions, adb

I want to grant **android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION** to my apk file.

adb command i used:

> adb shell pm grant myPackageName
>   android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION

but there is always the same error again and again:

> Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: myPackageName has
>   not requested permission android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="14" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
```

Permissions are already granted:

```
grantedPermissions:
  android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
  android.permission.GET_TASKS
  android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
  android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
  android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS
  android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
  android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
  android.permission.CALL_PHONE
  android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
  android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS
  android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
  android.permission.READ_SMS
  android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
  android.permission.CAMERA
  android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
  android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS
  android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY
  android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
  android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
  android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
  android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS
  com.skype.android.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
  com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
  android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
  android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS
  android.permission.READ_PROFILE
  android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD
  android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS
  android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
  android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
  android.permission.BLUETOOTH
  android.permission.INTERNET
  android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
  com.skype.permission.ACCOUNT
  android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS
  android.permission.VIBRATE
  com.skype.android.app.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE
```

What is the solution for this? Posts on google does not help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091022/listing-permissions-of-android-application-via-adb

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya This link is not for granting permissions ,is display permissions. I mean i got this error when i grant permissions.

Comment: Which device and version of Android are you using? I've tested the `pm grant` command on a Nexus 6 using Android 6 (MRA58N), it worked.

Comment: @cuihtlauac I am using nexus 5 Android 4.4, it doesn't work. I don't know why?Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

My phone is running android pie and it isn't rooted. An app that i installed required me to grant it permissions using `adb`. Initially I got the error

> java.lang.SecurityException: grantRuntimePermission: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS.

After searching my developer options, one seemed interesting - **Disable permission monitoring**. It wasn't enabled. After enabling, ran the command

```
adb -d shell pm grant packageName android.permission.DUMP
```

It worked!

Comment: question ask for solution of error on running "grant". Please read it carefully before answering.

Answer (score 0):

if you need grant in android 10+ ,plase try on usb debugging(safe mode) or usb install ,because my device is android 11 on Redmi 11

---- on off use grant ------

```
Exception occurred while executing 'grant':
java.lang.SecurityException: grantRuntimePermission: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS.
```