# Cannot write file to external SDcard on android 6.0

Tags: android, permissions, android-external-storage

My device is Android 6.0.1 operating system, but cannot write file to external SD card, from the log, there is no authority, but I have the right to apply for success, and that the permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml file;

I use the "adb shell dumpsys package packagename" command,  read and write permissions are returned to the true;
Then I looked at the Settings-> Apps->My Application - > Permissions, read and write permissions have been granted;

I must use an external SD card

Has anyone encountered this problem, I think this is very strange

```
private void requestPermiss() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission_group.STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "We need to read file from sdcard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            }, 0);
        }

    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(requestCode == 0){
        if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            writeFile();
        }
    }
}

private void writeFile(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String sdDir = getPath_For23(MainActivity.this, 0);
            File file = new File(sdDir + "/test.txt");
            if(!file.exists()){
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

private static String getPath_For23(Context context, int flag) {
    try {
        StorageManager sManager = (StorageManager) context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
        Class class_StorageManager = StorageManager.class;
        Method method_getVolumes = class_StorageManager.getMethod("getVolumes");

        Class<?> class_VolumeInfo = Class.forName("android.os.storage.VolumeInfo");
        Method method_getPath = class_VolumeInfo.getMethod("getPath");
        Method method_getDisk = class_VolumeInfo.getMethod("getDisk");

        Class<?> class_DiskInfo = Class.forName("android.os.storage.DiskInfo");
        Method method_isSd = class_DiskInfo.getMethod("isSd");
        Method method_isUsb = class_DiskInfo.getMethod("isUsb");

        List<Object> volumes = (List<Object>) method_getVolumes.invoke(sManager);
        for (Object volumeInfo : volumes) {
            File file = (File) method_getPath.invoke(volumeInfo);
            if (file != null) {
                Object diskInfo = method_getDisk.invoke(volumeInfo);
                if (diskInfo != null) {
                    boolean isSd = (boolean) method_isSd.invoke(diskInfo);
                    boolean isUsb = (boolean) method_isUsb.invoke(diskInfo);
                    switch (flag){
                        case 0:
                            if (isSd) {
                                return  file.getAbsolutePath();
                            }
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            if (isUsb) {
                                return file.getAbsolutePath();
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
 }
```

Error log:

> W/System.err: java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission
>   denied)
>
> W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
>
> W/System.err:     at
>   com.example.user.test60.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:70)
>
> W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>
> W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed:
>   EACCES (Permission denied)
>
> W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
>
> W/System.err:     at
>   libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
>
> W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:932)
>
> W/System.err:     ... 2 more

Comment: try Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); to get the path..

Comment: It will return /storage/emulated/0, this internal sdcard path , not external sdcard

Comment: Ok, are you sure the correct permissions are set? You check only READ... to show the permissions set http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091022/listing-permissions-of-android-application-via-adb
do you really need the sdcard? Google recommends the internal storage to use (faster, more secure, you can rely on...)

Comment: I have checked WRITE.... , and use dumpsys package packagename, it return granted=true both read and write permission.

Comment: weird. the exception is raised in main line 70. this is where you call the new file, isn't it?

Comment: Please tell the exact path for your sd card.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String imgLocation = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/FolderName/", fileName;
                FileOutputStream fOut = null;
                Date date = new Date();
                File dir = new File(imgLocation);
                if (!dir.exists()) {
                    dir.mkdirs();
                }
                fileName = "img" + date.getTime() + ".jpg";
                file = new File(dir, fileName);
                try {
                    Bitmap imageBitmap = bm;
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: no, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() will return /storage/emulated/0, point to internal sdcard , not external sdcard, I want to write file to external sdcard

Comment: hmm.. i thought it works for both.. thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 0):

Heads up, `getExternalFilesDirectory()` != `getExternalFilesDirs()`

I am quite sure that getExternalFilesDirs(String) will do the job. check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html

they say:

> In devices with multiple shared/external storage directories, this
>   directory represents the primary storage that the user will interact
>   with. Access to secondary storage is available
>   throughgetExternalFilesDirs(String),getExternalCacheDirs(),
>   and getExternalMediaDirs()

Comment: Yes, these methods can really return to the external SD card directory, but can only get to the application directory, but if my file on the SD card root directory, this method is not accessible

Answer (score 0):

An SD card on modern Android versions like 6.0 is read only.

The only place where your app can write is in a app specific directory on it.

Look at the second item returned by `getExternalFilesDirs()` for that path.

Comment: I've tried it, and it's internal sdcrad, it can only get the directory of the specified type

Comment: +Victor, use getExternalFilesDirS() and not getExternalFilesDir()...the first one returns an array..please check the value at index 1, it should be the SD card

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This will get needed permissions.

Comment: This has been added